# Ruby background OS X app

Tags: ruby, macos, background

It is easy to create ruby OS X app — create structure like this:

```
xxx.app
└── Contents
    ├── Info.plist
    ├── MacOS
    │   └── xxx
    └── Resources
        └── xxx.icns
```

and put code to execute into xxx. But launch time is noticeable, so I want this app to stay in background and run some method, when app is opened: so when I run that app first time, it executes code an stays in background, when I run another time, app is already in background, so it just runs specified method.

Minimal `Info.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
  <string>APPL</string>
  <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
  <string>newTabHere</string>
  <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
  <string>newTabHere</string>
  <key>LSUIElement</key>
  <true/><!-- hides icon from Dock -->
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: @tig This is a great question/tip on its own. Given that you have xxx placed in three spots and say "put code to execute into xxx", is it required to have the same string for all three?

Comment: @Phrogz: This structure is standard for OS X apps, so names for executable and icns file are specified in `Info.plist` and those names can be different. I'll add content of minimal `Info.plist` to the question.

Comment: @Phrogz: About my question — it seems to me that creating such app is sort of a hack, as app icon (if not hidden) bounces in Dock until program finishes and opening app with long running script inside multiple times in a row will not do anything, so it seems that it is hard or impossible to creating running loop in such app. I think I'll have to use MacRuby if i want to create OS X app using ruby.

Comment: This should work as you mentioned... I tested it with shell script and it runs perfectly in background without any visual indication. Does your ruby application have some visual components/libraries that produce the icon (like in python pylab or xquartz)? What osx version you have (I have 10.6.5)?

Comment: @Juha: I am also on 10.6.5. My application is a simple ruby script which opens new Terminal tab next to current with same working dir and it should work even if current tab is busy (executing something) and it works fine, but takes some time to start and if system is busy, than it can take some seconds, that is why I want it to run in background.

Comment: hmm, I think the problem is somewhere else than in your app... See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slowness is due to the start up time required for the ruby interpreter. That is why it is not slow for a bash script or objective-c.

**Steps to communicate with background ruby program:**

- Make your ruby program use the [daemons gem](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/).(optional, but makes running in background easier)
- Write a bash script to telnet to a port when run.
- Have your ruby program run [eventmachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/)(avaliable via Rubygems) or another socket server that supports telnet.
- When the ruby socket server receives the message over telnet have the program run the method you want.
- Package the bash script in an application like you describe in your question.

**The bash script has to:**

1. Launch the ruby program or start the daemon if it is not already running in the background.
2. Connect with telnet to localhost on the port specified in the ruby program
3. Send a message to run the method.
4. Save or print the result.

**Advantages to this solution**

- Easy to implement.
- Telnet is automatically installed on all macs.
- Bash scripts are easy to learn to use.
- Ruby has good socket gems and libraries that are easy to implement.

**Warning**

This has the cost of constantly using up the computer's memory with the ruby interpreter. So, it is not a user friendly solution.

To create a true app with a graphical interface in ruby you have to use macruby with rubycocoa.

Or use the Titanium Desktop from Appcelerator, you will have to write the interface code in javascript but you can do the rest with ruby. This method also has the advantage of being cross-platform. see http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/desktop/ruby

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by 'run in the background'. To have it open, do its thing, and close without taking over the screen in any way, you could probably set the property list to hide the status bar icon [cite](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/docktasks_cocoa/docktasks_cocoa.html) and to close. You can use use automator to open, run the script, and close.

Comment: No, its LSUIElement is already true, I mean staying in background and executing some method when application is called another time. My intention is to minimize time spent on opening app, starting ruby interpretter, etc…

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you have done it. I tested it with a simple script as executable (in your code the script is in the place of xxx):

```
#!/bin/sh
a=0
echo $a >> /tmp/test.txt
```

And I timed it:

```
> time /usr/bin/open test.app

real    0m0.042s
user    0m0.022s
sys     0m0.010s
```

So the application starts in 40 ms (and if background it should return roughly at the same time). The problem might be how you open the application (command line, icon, applescript...). Could you tell more?

**edit:** If you use terminal to open, you can use the '&' sign at the end (starts a background process). If I do that the shell returns in 6 ms.

br,

Juha